# Rails 6 images shows on heroku local but not on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I made a ruby on rails app. It works perfectly on heroku local (locally) but after being deployed to heroku, the images breaks.

The images are saved as .png in the images folder, in the assets folder, which is in the app folder.
Also got 404 errors on my console:

```
jorden.png:1 GET https://shoehouse-org.herokuapp.com/assets/jorden.png 404 (Not Found)
```

[image: directories]

```
#views/shoes/index.html.erb
  <% @shoes.each do |shoe| %>
  <div class="column">
    <img src=<%= "/assets/#{shoe.img_url}" %> alt="Snow" style="width:100%">    
  </div>
```

I also set the following lines to true in production.rb file.

```
      config.serve_static_assets = true
      config.assets.compile = true
      config.assets.digest = true
```

Gemfile includes:

```
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
<img src=<%= "#{image_url(shoe.img_url)}" %> alt="Snow" style="width:100%">
```